# Can not override Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type.php in magento2

Tags: magento2, catalog, bundle

issue with _construct method:

this is my di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type" type="Vendor\ProductOptionMsg\Model\Product\Type" />
</config>
```

this is my Type.php:

```
<?PHP
   /**
   * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */

    namespace Vendor\ProductOptionMsg\Model\Product;

    use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\Collection as Selections;
    use Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\Collection\FilterApplier as SelectionCollectionFilterApplier;
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
    use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;
    use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
    use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;

   class Type extends \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type
    {
    /**
 * Product type
 */
const TYPE_CODE = 'bundle';

/**
 * Product is composite
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_isComposite = true;

/**
 * Cache key for Options Collection
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_keyOptionsCollection = '_cache_instance_options_collection';

/**
 * Cache key for Selections Collection
 *
 * @var string
 * @deprecated 100.2.0
 */
protected $_keySelectionsCollection = '_cache_instance_selections_collection';

/**
 * Cache key for used Selections
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_keyUsedSelections = '_cache_instance_used_selections';

/**
 * Cache key for used selections ids
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_keyUsedSelectionsIds = '_cache_instance_used_selections_ids';

/**
 * Cache key for used options
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_keyUsedOptions = '_cache_instance_used_options';

/**
 * Cache key for used options ids
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_keyUsedOptionsIds = '_cache_instance_used_options_ids';

/**
 * Product is possible to configure
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $_canConfigure = true;

/**
 * Catalog data
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data
 */
protected $_catalogData = null;

/**
 * Catalog product
 *
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product
 */
protected $_catalogProduct = null;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory
 */
protected $_bundleOption;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection
 */
protected $_bundleSelection;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config
 */
protected $_config;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_bundleCollection;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory
 */
protected $_bundleFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection
 */
protected $_bundleModelSelection;

/**
 * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
 */
protected $priceCurrency;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
 */
protected $_stockRegistry;

/**
 * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface
 */
protected $_stockState;

/**
 * @var MetadataPool
 */
private $metadataPool;

/**
 * @var SelectionCollectionFilterApplier
 */
private $selectionCollectionFilterApplier;

/**
 * @var ArrayUtils
 */
private $arrayUtility;

 /**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
 * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData
 * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection
 * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory $bundleFactory
 * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory $bundleCollection
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config
 * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection $bundleSelection
 * @param \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory $bundleOption
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
 * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
 * @param MetadataPool|null $metadataPool
 * @param SelectionCollectionFilterApplier|null $selectionCollectionFilterApplier
 * @param ArrayUtils|null $arrayUtility
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType,
    \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
    \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $catalogProduct,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data $catalogData,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\SelectionFactory $bundleModelSelection,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\BundleFactory $bundleFactory,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection\CollectionFactory $bundleCollection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection $bundleSelection,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\OptionFactory $bundleOption,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
    Json $serializer = null,
    MetadataPool $metadataPool = null,
    SelectionCollectionFilterApplier $selectionCollectionFilterApplier = null,
    ArrayUtils $arrayUtility = null
) {
    $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
    $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_bundleOption = $bundleOption;
    $this->_bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
    $this->_config = $config;
    $this->_bundleCollection = $bundleCollection;
    $this->_bundleFactory = $bundleFactory;
    $this->_bundleModelSelection = $bundleModelSelection;
    $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    $this->_stockState = $stockState;

    $this->metadataPool = $metadataPool
        ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(MetadataPool::class);

    $this->selectionCollectionFilterApplier = $selectionCollectionFilterApplier
        ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SelectionCollectionFilterApplier::class);
    $this->arrayUtility= $arrayUtility ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(ArrayUtils::class);

    parent::__construct(
        $catalogProductOption,
        $eavConfig,
        $catalogProductType,
        $eventManager,
        $fileStorageDb,
        $filesystem,
        $coreRegistry,
        $logger,
        $productRepository,
        $serializer
    );
}

/**
 * Prepare product and its configuration to be added to some products list.
 *
 * Perform standard preparation process and then prepare of bundle selections options.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $buyRequest
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
 * @param string $processMode
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase|array|string
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
protected function _prepareProduct(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $buyRequest, $product, $processMode)
{
    $result = parent::_prepareProduct($buyRequest, $product, $processMode);
    
    try {
        if (is_string($result)) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($result));
        }

        $selections = [];
        $isStrictProcessMode = $this->_isStrictProcessMode($processMode);

        $skipSaleableCheck = $this->_catalogProduct->getSkipSaleableCheck();
        $_appendAllSelections = (bool)$product->getSkipCheckRequiredOption() || $skipSaleableCheck;

        $options = $buyRequest->getBundleOption();
        
        
        if (is_array($options)) {
            $options = $this->recursiveIntval($options);
            $optionIds = array_keys($options);


           /*  if (empty($optionIds) && $isStrictProcessMode) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please specify product option(s).'));
            }  */

            $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);
            $optionsCollection = $this->getOptionsCollection($product);
            $this->checkIsAllRequiredOptions(
                $product,
                $isStrictProcessMode,
                $optionsCollection,
                $options
            );

            $selectionIds = array_values($this->arrayUtility->flatten($options));
            // If product has not been configured yet then $selections array should be empty
            if (!empty($selectionIds)) {
                $selections = $this->getSelectionsByIds($selectionIds, $product);

                if (count($selections->getItems()) !== count($selectionIds)) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __('The options you selected are not available.')
                    );
                }

                // Check if added selections are still on sale
                $this->checkSelectionsIsSale(
                    $selections,
                    $skipSaleableCheck,
                    $optionsCollection,
                    $options
                );

                $optionsCollection->appendSelections($selections, true, $_appendAllSelections);

                $selections = $selections->getItems();
            } else {
                $selections = [];
            }
        } else {
            $product->setOptionsValidationFail(true);
            $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->setStoreFilter($product->getStoreId(), $product);

            $optionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->getOptionsCollection($product);
            $optionIds = $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->getOptionsIds($product);
            $selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->getSelectionsCollection($optionIds, $product);
            $options = $optionCollection->appendSelections($selectionCollection, true, $_appendAllSelections);

            $selections = $this->mergeSelectionsWithOptions($options, $selections);
        }
        if ((is_array($selections) && count($selections) > 0) || !$isStrictProcessMode) {
            $uniqueKey = [$product->getId()];
            $selectionIds = [];
            $qtys = $buyRequest->getBundleOptionQty();

            // Shuffle selection array by option position
            usort($selections, [$this, 'shakeSelections']);

            foreach ($selections as $selection) {
                $selectionOptionId = $selection->getOptionId();
                $qty = $this->getQty($selection, $qtys, $selectionOptionId);

                $selectionId = $selection->getSelectionId();
                $product->addCustomOption('selection_qty_' . $selectionId, $qty, $selection);
                $selection->addCustomOption('selection_id', $selectionId);

                $beforeQty = $this->getBeforeQty($product, $selection);
                $product->addCustomOption('product_qty_' . $selection->getId(), $qty + $beforeQty, $selection);

                /*
                 * Create extra attributes that will be converted to product options in order item
                 * for selection (not for all bundle)
                 */
                $price = $product->getPriceModel()
                    ->getSelectionFinalTotalPrice($product, $selection, 0, 1);
                $attributes = [
                    'price' => $price,
                    'qty' => $qty,
                    'option_label' => $selection->getOption()
                        ->getTitle(),
                    'option_id' => $selection->getOption()
                        ->getId(),
                ];

                $_result = $selection->getTypeInstance()
                    ->prepareForCart($buyRequest, $selection);
                $this->checkIsResult($_result);

                $result[] = $_result[0]->setParentProductId($product->getId())
                    ->addCustomOption(
                        'bundle_option_ids',
                        $this->serializer->serialize(array_map('intval', $optionIds))
                    )
                    ->addCustomOption(
                        'bundle_selection_attributes',
                        $this->serializer->serialize($attributes)
                    );

                if ($isStrictProcessMode) {
                    $_result[0]->setCartQty($qty);
                }

                $resultSelectionId = $_result[0]->getSelectionId();
                $selectionIds[] = $resultSelectionId;
                $uniqueKey[] = $resultSelectionId;
                $uniqueKey[] = $qty;
            }

            // "unique" key for bundle selection and add it to selections and bundle for selections
            $uniqueKey = implode('_', $uniqueKey);
            foreach ($result as $item) {
                $item->addCustomOption('bundle_identity', $uniqueKey);
            }
            $product->addCustomOption(
                'bundle_option_ids',
                $this->serializer->serialize(
                    array_map('intval', $optionIds)
                )
            );
            $product->addCustomOption('bundle_selection_ids', $this->serializer->serialize($selectionIds));

            return $result;
        }
    } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $this->getSpecifyOptionMessage();
}
```

throws below error while running di:compile :

[image]

throws error on product page:

[image]

Comment: please attach error

Comment: check i have attach error

Comment: try to run this command : - php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Comment: ok  let me try this

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Magento version?

Comment: version is 2.3.2